# Hightlight Gutter of Function Being Edited

Tags: colorscheme

Is it possible to change the back-gound color of the gutter for the function that I am working on?  I keep loosing my place, but it would be awesome to highlight a section like below.

[image]

Comment: Approaching this differently, you could use folding. Then `zx` will fold everything that's not under the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

One could (ab)use `:help sign`:

```
" define an highlight group
highlight CurrentBlock ctermbg=red ctermfg=red cterm=NONE

" define a sign
sign define currentblock text=>> texthl=CurrentBlock

" place the signs
for range(30, 40)
    execute "sign place " . i . " line=" . i . " name=currentblock file=" . expand("%:p")
endfor

" remove the signs
for range(30, 40)
    execute "sign unplace" . i
endfor
```

and wrap all that in a `CursorMoved` autocommand.

The hardest part being to actually determine where the current block starts and ends.

[image: signs]

Comment: Sharing the thought - it is abuse :-)

Comment: Is it possible to highlight gutter between two marks, lets say when the user places mark `a` and mark `b`, the system highlights everything in between?

Comment: Yes, you can use `line("'a")` to get the line number of `'a`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns) plugin like this:

First, define after what rules to higlight the gutter.

```
fu! CustomSignExpression(lnum)
    if a:lnum < line('w0') || a:lnum > line ('w$')
        return 0
    endif
    if !exists("#CustomSignExpression#CursorMoved")
        augroup CustomSignExpression
            au!
            au VimResized,CursorMoved * :unlet! s:min s:max | :UpdateSigns
        augroup end
    endif
    if !exists("s:min")
        let s:min=search('^{', 'bn')
        let s:max=search('^}', 'n')
    endif
    if a:lnum < s:min || a:lnum > s:max
        return 0
    else
        return 'Gutter2'
    endif
endfu
```

This function is a slight adjustment, to what is documented in the help at `:h :SignExpression`. You most likely want to adjust the search patterns, e.g. according to your screenshot you probably want something like `^\w\+(.*)\s*{` as the search pattern for the start of a function.

Now you can use `:SignExpression CustomSignExpression(v:lnum)` and it should highlight your gutter column with red. If you want a different highlighting, Adjust the 'Gutter' line inside the function. See the help at  `:h Signs-Highlight` for what is predefined and how you can change that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to highlight the gutter (and the fact that the only highlight groups for that region are `LineNr` and `CursorLineNr` makes me think that's not possible), but you could use `:match` the given function:

```
:highlight WorkInProgress ctermbg=DarkGray
:match WorkInProgress /^TEST_F(CborEncoder, write32bit_uint) {\_.\{-}\n}/
```

When you're done, you can use `:match none` to clear it.

Answer (score 2):

I was really surprised by the existence of [`SignColumn`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27signcolumn%27), so I decided to use it in this strange way. The whole function is not highlighted

```
"if a change in a text, call SetSign() function
au TextChanged,TextChangedI * :cal SetSign()

function! SetSign()
   "remove signs 
   sign unplace *
   "define a sign
   sign define lastMod text=* texthl=Search
   "place a sign
   exe ":sign place 1 line=" . line("'.") . " name=lastMod file=" . expand("%:p")
endfunction

"remove the signs manually
nnoremap <leader>u :sign unplace *<CR>
```

but at least the last changed line in code is highlighted at the side. If you want to remove the sign, just press `<leader>+u` in normal mode.

Nevertheless, this solution is not so great, so it is probably better to use [`` `. ``](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%60.), [`g;`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#g%3B) and [`g,`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#g%2C), or [`gi`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#gi) to get to the position where the last change was made (and which I presumed was the position of the function you working on).

Read more in

- [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html)
- [`:h sign.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/sign.txt.html)